# Unique in an ifelse statement in R

Tags: r, if-statement, null, unique

I am having trouble showing a vector of the unique values when I put call a `unique` on a vector in an `ifelse` statement as seen below.

```
> row <- c(1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3)
> unique(row)
[1] 1 3
> ifelse(is.null(NULL), unique(row), 2)
[1] 1
```

I would like for the ifelse statement to return the same as `unique(row)` if indicated that it is `NULL`.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: `ifelse` is a vectorized function that returns a vector the same length as the first parameter (`length(is.null(NULL))`). It cannot return vectors of different lengths. You'd need to use a standard `if/else` statement for that.

Comment: @MrFlick I see - `if(is.null(NULL)) {unique(row)} else {2}` worked smoothly! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be solved with an `if/else` statement:

```
> if(is.null(NULL)) {unique(row)} else {2}
[1] 1 3
```